# Select Multiple Elements for Image Modal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, selector, getelementbyid

I want to use a selector to select every image on the page for putting into the modal without rewriting the entire script for each image.  I feel like this a is a dumb question but I keep striking out trying different things.  Right now I'm using var img = document.getElementById("article01"); to select one image because that's all you can do with getElementById. So I want to select both the images listed so that I'm not rewriting the entire script for each image because there will be many more on the page. I tried using getelementbyclass and tagname but I think I'm stuck.

HTML:

```
<!-- Trigger the Modal -->
    <img id="article01" src="/images/article1.PNG" alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
    <img id="article01-2" src="/images/article1-2.PNG" alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
<!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="modal1" class="modal">

    <!-- The Close Button -->
    <span class="close">&times;</span>

    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

    <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
    <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    <script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("modal1");

    *var img = document.getElementById("article01");*
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    img.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` to get a **[nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** of all of the images.  For example, if you created your list of images as such:

```
<img class="selectable" src="article-1" />
<img class="selectable" src="article-2" />
<img class="selectable" src="article-2" />
```

You can add an event listener to each using ...

```
document.querySelectorAll('img.selectable')
  .forEach((img) => {
    img.addEventListener('click', (e) => showModal(e.target)); //or use img.onclick = ...
  });
```

Here is a link to a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/rbanning/pres/b8edfb450eca532f3368098ca72f467e) showing a demo of how to do this...

Comment: I'm going to implement this now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what i got from your post. I think what you are looking for is document.querySelector()

```
<!-- Trigger the Modal -->
<img alt="this is a caption" src="https://livebrooks.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/fpo.gif" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
<img alt="this is the second caption" src="https://livebrooks.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/fpo.gif" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modalWrap" class="modal">
  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close" onclick="document.querySelector('#modalWrap').remove()">&times;</span>

</div>
```

```js
for (var i of document.querySelectorAll("img")) {
  makeModal(i.src, i.getAttribute("alt"));
}


function makeModal(src, caption) {
  //modal wrap
  var modalWrap = document.querySelector("#modalWrap");
  //img
  var imgElement = document.createElement("img");
  imgElement.src = src;
  imgElement.style.maxWidth = "300px";
  //caption
  var captionElement = document.createElement("p");
  captionElement.innerText = caption;

  //adding elements to modalWrap
  modalWrap.appendChild(imgElement);
  modalWrap.appendChild(captionElement);

}
```